# SAAB 93 2001 TiD countershaft sleeve

Tags: part-identification, saab

I'm looking for a part for a 2001 SAAB 93 2.2 TiD but I'm not 100% sure what the name of the part is.
Essentially it's a sleeve that goes in to the differential which the part in the attached image goes in to:

[image]

I've been searching around and from what I gather, the term SAAB uses to describe it is "countershaft insert into diff bearing".

Any help locating one of these parts would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Lee.

Comment: Like the oil seal? Or the snap ring? Or the actual pinion that that shaft meshes with?

Comment: @Nick Well we have the oil seal, but there's a "sleeve" which is supposed to hold the drive shaft end firmly in place. It sits on the part where you can see the diagonal ridges. I'll try and get a pic in the morning.

Comment: Ok, some bushing of somesort. Your best bet would be a fiche with an exploded view and and part numbers. I don't know where you could find one for Saabs.

Comment: Check for a official service center near you, they might help: http://www.saab.com/en-us/usa/the-company/service-centers/locate-service-center/

Answer (score 3):

The part on the picture is called "Companion flange" as per Saab's own electronic part catalogue (EPC) - number 7 on the drawing below. I'm not sure which one in particular you need, so here's the drawing itself:

[image]

<sup>[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pQSQ.png)</sup>

Check whether your engine type is among the listed above. Part numbers are listed on the right, and you can use those when ordering the components.

This is for Saab 9-3 first generation, which includes your model.